# youtube api for personal upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

hi guys I want to use youtube api to upload videos by program.

cuz it's only used by myself, I

1. register a domain like sample.com
2. set a google workspace cuz it's the only way to set the app internal

But now I meet the problem.

When I add the user to the google workspace, it can't add the gmail only create the main with name@sample.com.

**Not the gmail that my youtube channel is.**

So I still can't upload videos to my youtube channel by programing.

please tell me what to do after you saw this. thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about account management with YouTube and Google, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set this up with a workspace account.  This means that the the user would need to be on the domain.  Not a standard gmail account.

You could try to transfer the YouTube channel to the workspace domain but im not sure if that's even possible.  Or try to grant the domain email access to the YouTube channel.